# Can the bytecode of a class change if a parent class/interface changes?

Tags: java, class, bytecode

I'm trying to determine if I need to recompile some jars in our build chain, if I have for example the following structure, jar 1 compiles when its' source changes and jar 2 compiles when its' source changes or when jar 1 has recompiled.

jar 1:

```
public class Foo /* impl*/
```

jar 2:

```
public class Bar extends Foo /*impl*/
```

**Assuming the contract between the 2 classes doesn't change**, ie. an abstract method is added or a method is added to an interface, etc.

Do I need to recompile jar 2? ie. if some changes are made to a private method within Foo would Bar need to be recompiled?

I tried testing this by comparing the bytecode of two classes after changing a bunch in one and as expected it did not change. My coworkers however insist that they have encountered situations where even though the contract was unchanged they had to recompile everything for it to work, however they can't remember what the reason was... So the burden of proof is on me to show that that should not be necessary. **Is there a case where making a change to a superclass will require the subclass to be recompiled even though the interface between the two has remained the same?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say `Foo` is released by an open source organization; and there are thousands of subclasses of `Foo` implemented by various companies.

Now if some changes are made to `Foo`, and a new version is released in binary form, should all companies recompile their code? Of course not. (well, we do recompile all code all the time, but it is not required - the new jar of `Foo` can be simply dropped in without causing any problems)

This is the issue of binary compatibility, and you can check the spec to make sure that a change to `Foo` is safe. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I guess I was hoping that as long as the source didn't change, the class file would never need to change. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

In general case you have to recompile dependent class. However if you have not changed any  methods or fields of `Foo` that are used by `Bar` you do not have to recompile `Bar` when `Foo` is changed.

For example if `Foo` had method `protected int foo()` called by `Bar` but you changed it signature to `protected String foo()` or changed its visibility to `private` you have to re-compile `Bar`. In this case `Bar` cannot be compiled: you have to change its code.

However if `Bar` does not use method `foo()` or if only implementation details of `foo()` were changed you can use `Bar` without re-compilation.

Comment: changing a constant value in Foo which Bar uses would also require a recompile.

Comment: also, java has well defined rules for [binary compatibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html).

Comment: There are also potential issues with method overloading. Obviously if an overloaded method is added, it won't be used without recompilation.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely No. You can use frameworks (that contains a lot of classes with contract like Foo) that packaged in jar file and you do not need to compile them from source. But you need to be absolutely sure that contract hasn't been changed directly on indirectly. Some exmaple of indirect change:

```
public class Foo { //v1
    public static final int CONSTANT = 1;         
}

public class Foo { //v2
    public static final int CONSTANT = 2;         
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    private int a(int value) {
        switch (value) {
            case CONSTANT:
                return 1;
        }
        return 2;
    }
}
```

If you do not recompile class Bar it will still use value 1.

Comment: Does that then mean that the Bar.class file will have the value of the `CONSTANT` int inside of it? My intuition would say it only has a refrerence to `Foo/CONSTANT` and will be updated accordingly at runtime. Any idea why that would not be the case?

Comment: if you will use something else than _switch_ than probably yes. Switch instruction requires explicit numbers and it is not possible for compile to read value from CONSTANT field in runtime.